# Google Calendar API service account authorization not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to authorize my app with google's API for google calendar using a service account. Now I have encountered a problem where, for some reason, the credentials are not being loaded.

This is my authorization code:

```
scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scopes)
cal = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
cal.authorization = authorization
cal.authorization.fetch_access_token!
```

Here is the error message that I'm getting:
[image]

I have the client_secrets.json file in my ENV variables as described in google's docs. I also have each element from that file as an ENV variable as it is specified in the google auth source code.

Can anyone offer any insight on getting the authorization working?

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar problem.  Did you authorize the service account's email address on your calendar? Just go to the google calendar, hover over the name and then under sharing, add the email address of the service account with the appropriate permissions. That solved the problem for me.

Comment: That wasn't the issue for me as I had all that taken care of beforehand. The problem was in how I had tried to get the client_secrets.json file's contents into Heroku's ENV variables. I figured it out with a bit of trial and error though.

Answer (score 0):

It is strongly encouraged in [Using OAuth 2.0 for Server to Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) that you use libraries, such as the Google APIs client libraries.

As discussed in [Creating a service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount),

> If your application doesn't run on Google App Engine or Google Compute Engine, you must obtain these credentials in the Google API Console. To generate service-account credentials, or to view the public credentials that you've already generated, do the following:
>
> 1. Open the [**Service accounts page**](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cloudconsole&ltmpl=api&osid=1&passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fconsole.developers.google.com%2Fpermissions%2Fserviceaccounts&flowName=GlifWebSignIn). If prompted, select a project.
> 2. Click **Create service account**.
> 3. In the **Create service account** window, type a name for the service account, and select **Furnish a new private key**. If you want to [grant G Suite domain-wide authority](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority) to the service account, also select **Enable G Suite Domain-wide Delegation**. Then click **Create**.
>
> Your new public/private key pair is generated and downloaded to your machine; it serves as the only copy of this key. You are responsible for storing it securely.

Furthermore, I also suggest that you please visit [Google Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#callingruby) for a more detailed information regarding default credentials.

For [Ruby](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials#callingruby), default credentials are provided by the Google APIs Client Library for Ruby, versions 0.1.0 and newer. In calling the application default credentials in application code, import the `googleauth` gem, then pass the scopes you need to access to `Google::Auth.get_application_default`:

```
require 'googleauth'
scopes =  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only']
authorization = Google::Auth.get_application_default(scopes)
```

Then, use the credentials to access an API service as follows:

```
require "google/apis/storage_v1"
storage = Google::Apis::StorageV1::StorageService.new
storage.authorization = authorization
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry, but this answer doesn't help, as I've already done all of this and it does not address the problem.